# SELECT multiple values from one record

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I need to show data from database on my webpage by selecting checkboxes. The data are driving license code assigned to users in database, so if users checks one checkbox I want to display every person that have selected driving license but others too (if there are others).
Data in the database are written like this (for example):

```
A1,A,B1,BE,C
```

HTML FORM:

```
<form action="filter-results.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-check-inline">   
    <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vodic[]"  value="A1">A1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check-inline">   
    <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vodic[]"  value="A2">A2</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check-inline">   
    <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vodic[]"  value="A">A</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check-inline">   
    <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vodic[]"  value="B1">B1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check-inline">   
    <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vodic[]"  value="B">B</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check-inline">   
    <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vodic[]" value="BE">BE</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check-inline">   
    <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vodic[]" value="C1">C1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check-inline">   
    <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vodic[]" value="C1E">C1E</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check-inline">   
    <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vodic[]" value="C">C</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check-inline">   
    <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vodic[]" value="CE">CE</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check-inline">   
    <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vodic[]" value="D1">D1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check-inline">   
    <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vodic[]" value="D1E">D1E</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check-inline">   
    <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vodic[]" value="D">D</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check-inline">   
    <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vodic[]" value="DE">DE</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check-inline">   
    <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vodic[]" value="T">T</label>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
if(empty($_POST['license'])){
        $license = "";
    } else {
        $license = array();
        foreach ($_POST['license'] as $value){
            $license[] = $value;
        }
    }
```

PHP MYSQL QUERY:

```
query=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE vodicaky RLIKE '$license[]');
```

Comment: Yeah I know I am just getting to it, but thank you for your warning

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: Your query line has syntax errors. Is this actual code or did these errors happen when you were copying to the question?

Comment: What syntax errors? I think this happen when coyping the question

Comment: @luxx "RLIKE" Is not a valid MYSQL keyword..... In some SQL versions, it will not run in others it will, you wanna make sure that it is compatiable with your SQL version.....

Comment: @El_Vanja Correct me if I am wrong but I am pretty sure RLIKE matches REs and that '[]' is not a defined RE unless you wanted to litterally match a '[]' string??

Comment: These would be your syntax errors: 1) You don't have a closing  double quote `"` at the end of the query. 2) You're trying to insert an array as a string: `'$license[]'`. 3) Calling an array without a specified index is illegal (refers to the same piece of code). And this is assuming that the lack of `$` at the beginning of the line is merely because you accidentally didn't select it while copying.

Answer (score 3):

PHP does not expand arrays when you put them in strings. i.e. `$list = "$values[]"` doesn't work.

Next, putting a PHP variable directly into your query is extremely bad practice, & horribly insecure giving that this is user data, as mentioned in a comment above.

To solve your problem, you'll need to perform multiple `LIKE` checks. <strike>You shouldn't need regex here, so it's not `RLIKE`.</strike>

We'll assume your submission looks like this:

```php
$license = [
    'A1',
    'A',
    'B1',
];
```

And this is the query we're trying to build:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE vodicaky LIKE '%A1%' 
OR vodicaky LIKE '%A%'
OR vodicaky LIKE '%B1%'
```

Which will actually have issues because `LIKE %A%` will match A1 as well. This query would fetch more than you need & you could filter it down in php. Or you could go to the regex route & you'd need something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE vodicaky REGEXP '(^|,)A1(,|$)'
OR vodicaky REGEXP '(^|,)A(,|$)'
OR vodicaky REGEXP '(^|,)B1(,|$)'
```

`REGEXP` is a synonym for `RLIKE`, I think. I've always used `REGEXP`. I don't think it matters which you use.

`(^|,)A1(,|$)` says:

- The start of the string `^` OR a comma `,`
- Followed by `A1`
- Followed by a comma `,` OR the end of the string `$`

[Regexr](https://regexr.com/) is a fabulous place to play with regex. [rexegg](https://www.rexegg.com/) is a great resource for properly learning regex (reading required).

NOW, back to doing your query **without security vulnerabilities**. I use [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) which allows `:named_paramaters` for binding & haven't used `mysqli` in quite some time, and I believe `mysqli` only allows `?` binding. I'm not testing this code. But the actual query string you need to build is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE vodicaky REGEXP ?
OR vodicaky REGEXP ?
OR vodicaky REGEXP ?
```

Since you're binding, I don't think the `?`s need to be surrounded in quotes

Then you have to bind it. We're looking at [`mysqli prepared statements`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php):

```php
$licenses = //from POST
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);
$binds = [];
$bindTypes = '';
$query = [];
foreach ($licenses as $lic){
    $query[] = 'vodicaky LIKE ?'
    $binds[] = "(^|,){$lic}(,|$)";
    $bindTypes .= 's';
}

$qsImplode = implode("\nOR ", $query);
$qs = 
<<<SQL
SELECT * FROM USERS
WHERE {$qsImplode}
SQL;

// echo $qs; exit; // for debugging purposes. 

$statement = $mysqli->prepare($qs);
//here's where I'm less confident since I use PDO, not mysqli
$statement->bind_param($bindTypes, ...$binds);

//then execute your query & get your results.
```

So, I think that basically does it. Hope this all helps. I think you should be able to get it from here, even if my code has a couple errors.

Comment: & You should be able to just do `$license = $_POST['vodic'];` instead of doing that loop.

Comment: Wow man complex answer, I'll definitely try that later. May I let you know when find some issue?

Comment: @luxx, Sure thing! I won't make any promises about responsiveness, but I usually reply soon enough. And yeah, I realize it may be a lot to take in. `print_r/var_dump/echo`ing at different ponits can be a big help in making sense of things. gl hf!